# In Hibernate, hbm2ddl.auto = "update" is inserting records but also giving some exceptions?

Tags: hibernate

When I give update in the hibernate.cfg.xml file, when I give session.save() and transaction.commit(), the objects are getting saved in the DB but still getting some errors in the logs as below.

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table Profiles (username varchar(255) not null, First_Name varchar(255), Last_Name varchar(255), primary key (username))" via JDBC Statement
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)

and

> Caused by: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: object name already exists: PROFILES in statement [create table Profiles (username varchar(255) not null, First_Name varchar(255), Last_Name varchar(255), primary key (username)) ]
>       at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.execute(UcanaccessStatement.java:159)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)

I'm using MS Access db and below is my configuration file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:ucanaccess://E:/Eclipse_workspace_trails/DB/messenger.accdb
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver
        </property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show-sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="hibernate/profiles.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

Comment: Do you get this error when your sessionFactory loads?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: Are you getting sql queries in your console?

Comment: I got the below error..
Error executing DDL "create table Profiles (username varchar(255) not null, First_Name varchar(255), Last_Name varchar(255), primary key (username))" via JDBC Statement

I am also expecting the queries in the console as an effect of <property name="show-sql">true</property>, but no queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your properties to:

```
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
 <property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

Comment: adding 
            `<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">
             false
            </property>`
has removed the exceptions..
but still I couldn't see the sql queries in logs.